# Is the value returned by `ulimit -Hn` an optimistic limit or a tight, achievable limit?

Tags: linux, kernel, pam, ulimit

On my Linux machine, I have:

```
❯ ulimit -Sn       # Check soft limit
ulimit -Hn       # Check hard limit

1024
1048576
```

Does this mean that I can increase my max open files to 1048576, regardless of `/etc/security/limits.conf`, `/etc/pam.d/common-session*`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/security/limits.conf` is the configuration file of `pam_limits.so`, which sets the same limits the shell's `ulimit` command does. If the hard limit is set to 1048576, then you can raise the soft limit to that. But if `limits.conf` specifies a lower hard limit (when you log in via PAM), that's the one that should end up as the limit on your shell session.

Comment: But I can trust `ulimit`'s output, correct? I don't need to touch other config files if I am happy with what `ulimit` outputs.

Comment: @HappyFace, yeah, they're the `getrlimit()`/`setrlimit()` limits (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prlimit.2.html), they're tied to the process, and the kernel doesn't look at any config files when you try to set them. (of course stuff like SELinux could also affect it etc.)